# What do they mean by "then in the quote directories"?

Tags: c++, c, include-path

In page 8 of [The C Preprocessor version 10.0.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp.pdf) we have the following statement:

> `#include "file"`
>
> This variant is used for header files of your own
>   program. It searches for a file named `file` first in the directory
>   containing the current file, **then in the quote directories** and then
>   the same directories used for `<file>`. You can prepend directories to
>   the list of quote directories with the `‘-iquote’` option.

What is meant by "then in the quote directories"?

Comment: The quote directories are explicitly the directories specified with `-iquote`. There are no default quote directories.

Comment: fwiw the paragraph starting with "f you need separate control over the search paths..." in section 2.3 may shed some light on the used terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says:

> You can prepend directories to the list of quote directories with the ‘-iquote’ option.

Thus, "quote directories" are those directories that have been passed as arguments using the ‘-iquote’ option <sup>1</sup>. The documentation for the option says:

> -iquote dir
>
> Search dir only for header files requested with "#include " file ""; they are not searched for "#include < file >", before all
> directories specified by -I and before the standard system
> directories. If dir begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by
> the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.

<sup>1</sup> And in theory, from some other source. I don't know of any other documented source for quote dirs; no default list appears to be documented. I assume the list is empty by default.

Comment: i didnt find that first quote convincing in terms of explaining what is "the list of quote directories" because to prepend to a list there must be a list first. But I suppose thats just too much picking on words. Nevertheless it left me with a small doubt whether there is something in the list also when nothing is passed via `-iquote`

Comment: @eerorika I have erased my comment because I'm in doubt about it.

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's basically what I was thinking.

Comment: @idclev463035818 An empty list is still a list, which can be prepended to. It's important to know the order of elements of the list when the option is used multiple times, which I assume is reason for what the docs say. The possibility of default quote directories appears to neither be listed, nor explicitly stated as non-existing.

Answer (score 3):

gcc accepts several kinds of command-line parameters describing include directories:

`-I` - searched in case of `#include <file>` form and in case of `#include "file"` form if other methods fail

`-iquote` - searched only in case of `#include "file"` form if file is not found in the directory along with including file. It defines these "quote directories".

Comment: Don't forget the `-isystem` switch. There's also `--sysroot` which is related.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "quote directories" is not a standard term. Rather, this appears to be an ad hoc description of those directories searched by the quote form of `#include` but not by the angle-bracket form. It might be derived from the command line options used to specify directories where headers can be found (covered on pages 63-64 in the linked document).

- `-I dir` Think "Include directory"; `dir` is added to the list of directories searched for all `#include` directives.
- `-isystem dir` Think "system include directory"; `dir` is added to (the front of) the list of directories with system headers. (These headers *traditionally* use the angle-bracket form of `#include`, but that is not a requirement.) Since the directories for system headers are searched by both forms of `#include`, this option is largely redundant with `-I` (or perhaps `-I` should be viewed as largely redundant with this).
- `-iquote dir` Think "quote include directory"; `dir` is added to the (initially empty) list of directories to be searched for headers specified with the quote form of `#include`. (These headers *traditionally* are ones you write, but that is not enforced.) These directories are not searched for the angle-bracket version.

So "quote directories" are the directories where headers can live for the quote form of `#include` but not for the angle-bracket form. Often, this level of precision is not needed, and the `-I` option is sufficient. (Hence no need for a standard term for "quote directories".)

Answer (score 0):

The C standard says this:

> **6.10.2 Source file inclusion**
>   **Constraints**
>   A `#include` directive shall identify a header or source file that can be processed by the implementation.
>   **Semantics**
>   A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.
>   A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include "q-char-sequence" new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including `>` characters, if any) from the original directive.

In conclusion, the quote directories are the directories that are searched in an implementation-defined manner before the directories in the standard include path are searched.